# Biblatex - sort by appearance in article?

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
style=numeric
%style=alphabetic
%style=reading
]{biblatex}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\addbibresource{sample}
```

> In a nuclear reactor this process is controlled by control rods. These
>   control rods stops some of the neutrons and make the progess slower,
>   which keeps the chain reaction at a safe and stable level.
>   \cite{Wikipedia}
>
> has a very high pressure which spins the turbine and a generator, and
>   generate electrity. The water then enters a condenser to cool it down
>   and is send back to the reactor. \cite{U.S.NRC}

The problem is that in document the first cite is labeled "[2]" and the second cite "[1]". How do I sort it by appearence in the document?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Why do you have `\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}`?

Comment: Searched for solutions on google and that code appeard, but didn't work. I forgot to delete it, before I posted it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `sorting=none` to the `biblatex` options.

Comment: @RandomDude Glad it helped. As a general comment, you can also thank people by upvoting, and by accepting an answer (clicking the checkmark on the left) you mark the question as solved. You could consider doing that for all your questions, if they have been answered satisfyingly.